# Relationship between art and advertising in the passage

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaningful relationship between art and advertising in the following excerpt?

> She attended art school but was told by one of her instructors that
>   she was not good at **illustration**, that she should go into
>   **advertising** instead. So she took **advertising** classes and **fine arts** classes too until she was convinced by the head of an advertising agency that her work was really good, that she could be an
>   artist.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "meaningful relationship" in this question. Please clarify what you mean. Also please cite or link to the source of the quoted text.

Comment: I mean why was the illustration compared with advertising? @JamesK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various skill levels among artists (same as with any profession). She was told that her skill was not good enough to be an illustrator.

However, working as an artist in advertising (I presume due to a lower skill requirement) should be successful.